# C++ Impact analysis in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

If I have a large C++ solution and I change something, 
Is there any way with visual studio to determine what all modules are impacted?
Means is there any way to find all modules which are dependent on changed code.

Comment: What does "impacted" mean? What does "dependent" mean? There is "must be recompiled if file X.h is changed" and then there is "the logic will be wrong if some change in file X.cpp is made". And plenty of shades of gray between those.

Comment: Put your code into subversion and track the changes.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could try to use [Map dependencies with code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2019).You can visualize dependencies across your code by creating a code map.